# Обоснование запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

> Не важно, о чем человек говорит, если у него такой смех.

Помогите разобраться с первой запятой. На каком основании мы ее ставим (или не ставим)? СПП? А чем является *не важно*? Именным сказуемым? Постоянно сомневаюсь с запятыми в таких предложениях. С одной стороны, *о чем* — союз (это ведь союз?), который вводит придаточное, с другой — мне он кажется дополнением (говорит *о чем?* о чем).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(1) Не важно, (2) о чем человек говорит, (3)если у него такой смех.***

**Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с двумя придаточными**: (2) — изъяснительное и (3) — условное), отнесенными к одному главному предложению (1).

Это параллельное (неоднородное) подчинение, так как придаточные разного вида. **Запятые** между предложениями в СПП ставятся  согласно основному правилу.

Главное предложение — безличное, сказуемое **составное именное**, связка ***быть***  настоящем времени пропущена, именная часть выражена предикативным наречием ***не важно*** (словом категории состояния).

Наречие является опорным словом для выражения изъяснительных отношений (примеры других наречий: *плохо, хорошо, интересно* и др.).

**О ЧЁМ** — **союзное слово**, оно служит для связи предложений (1) и (2), а также является **дополнением** в придаточном предложении (2). (Этим союзные слова отличаются от союзов, которые служат только для связи предложений).

Comment: Вот именно такое объяснение мне было необходимо, спасибо вам!